# java- rotated file extraction?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to do a simple extraction of words from a PDF file. Then it inserts those words to a table in database. From what I have tested, a 90 degrees clockwise rotated text in PDF will gives gibberish result when I tried to extract the words.

For example, `database` in the file will yield `atabase` and also `database` itself as two different words. Obviously, `atabase` does not exist in the PDF file.

I tried converting the original file to be rotated upright and do the extraction and it works perfectly as expected. I understand this could be a limitation of the PDFBox itself.

So, in the case of someone trying to index a `rotated` PDF file, is there a way to tackle this?

Code snippet ( just for reference) :

```
 String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n");
    for (String line : lines) {
        String[] words = line.split(" ");

        System.out.println("Line: " + line);



        preparedStatement = con1.prepareStatement(sql);
        int i=0;
        for (String word : words) {

            // check if one or more special characters at end of string then remove OR
            // check special characters in beginning of the string then remove
            // insert every word directly to table db
            word = word.replaceAll("([\\W]+$)|(^[\\W]+)", "");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, path1);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, word);
              System.out.println("Token: " +word);
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        }


    }

    preparedStatement.close();


}
```

Comment: Please share an example PDF to reproduce the issue for.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1pe8zb9m5kajif/lol.pdf?dl=0

Comment: A bit late, but have you tried extracting with text sorting, i.e. with `stripper.setSortByPosition(true)`? Doing so improves the quality of the text extracted from your sample document considerably.

Comment: @mkl What I tried is rotating the 90 degrees file to upright and everything works as fine. I'll try what you suggested too.

Comment: Rotating the file upright works, too, but that requires manual interaction to first recognize which direction is upright (or a program that already does some text analysis).

Answer (score 2):

This is the PDFBox ExtractText command line utility, which can detect rotations since 2.0.13 ([PDFBOX-4371](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4371)). (That release had a bug with type 3 fonts, which was fixed ([PDFBOX-4390](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4390)) in the repository and in this code, and is in 2.0.14). Later code may have been improved since then. The current 2.0.* source can be found [here](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/tools/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/tools/ExtractText.java?view=markup).

To extract text from rotated files, use the "rotationMagic" setting. This setting first detects the angle of every glyph, collects these angles (`AngleCollector`), and in a second pass it does an extraction for every angle while discarding the rest (`FilteredTextStripper`). The order of extraction is by angle, which may or may not make sense if there are several different angles in a page.

The PDF is modified while extracting, so don't use this on documents you are saving.

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.apache.pdfbox.tools;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSArray;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSName;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentNameDictionary;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.filespecification.PDComplexFileSpecification;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.filespecification.PDEmbeddedFile;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.Matrix;

/**
 * This is the main program that simply parses the pdf document and transforms it
 * into text.
 *
 * @author Ben Litchfield
 * @author Tilman Hausherr
 */
public final class ExtractText
{
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(ExtractText.class);

    private static final String PASSWORD = "-password";
    private static final String ENCODING = "-encoding";
    private static final String CONSOLE = "-console";
    private static final String START_PAGE = "-startPage";
    private static final String END_PAGE = "-endPage";
    private static final String SORT = "-sort";
    private static final String IGNORE_BEADS = "-ignoreBeads";
    private static final String DEBUG = "-debug";
    private static final String HTML = "-html";
    private static final String ALWAYSNEXT = "-alwaysNext";
    private static final String ROTATION_MAGIC = "-rotationMagic";
    private static final String STD_ENCODING = "UTF-8";

    /*
     * debug flag
     */
    private boolean debug = false;

    /**
     * private constructor.
    */
    private ExtractText()
    {
        //static class
    }

    /**
     * Infamous main method.
     *
     * @param args Command line arguments, should be one and a reference to a file.
     *
     * @throws IOException if there is an error reading the document or extracting the text.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        // suppress the Dock icon on OS X
        System.setProperty("apple.awt.UIElement", "true");

        ExtractText extractor = new ExtractText();
        extractor.startExtraction(args);
    }
    /**
     * Starts the text extraction.
     *  
     * @param args the commandline arguments.
     * @throws IOException if there is an error reading the document or extracting the text.
     */
    public void startExtraction( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        boolean toConsole = false;
        boolean toHTML = false;
        boolean sort = false;
        boolean separateBeads = true;
        boolean alwaysNext = false;
        boolean rotationMagic = false;
        String password = "";
        String encoding = STD_ENCODING;
        String pdfFile = null;
        String outputFile = null;
        // Defaults to text files
        String ext = ".txt";
        int startPage = 1;
        int endPage = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for( int i=0; i<args.length; i++ )
        {
            if( args[i].equals( PASSWORD ) )
            {
                i++;
                if( i >= args.length )
                {
                    usage();
                }
                password = args[i];
            }
            else if( args[i].equals( ENCODING ) )
            {
                i++;
                if( i >= args.length )
                {
                    usage();
                }
                encoding = args[i];
            }
            else if( args[i].equals( START_PAGE ) )
            {
                i++;
                if( i >= args.length )
                {
                    usage();
                }
                startPage = Integer.parseInt( args[i] );
            }
            else if( args[i].equals( HTML ) )
            {
                toHTML = true;
                ext = ".html";
            }
            else if( args[i].equals( SORT ) )
            {
                sort = true;
            }
            else if( args[i].equals( IGNORE_BEADS ) )
            {
                separateBeads = false;
            }
            else if (args[i].equals(ALWAYSNEXT))
            {
                alwaysNext = true;
            }
            else if (args[i].equals(ROTATION_MAGIC))
            {
                rotationMagic = true;
            }
            else if( args[i].equals( DEBUG ) )
            {
                debug = true;
            }
            else if( args[i].equals( END_PAGE ) )
            {
                i++;
                if( i >= args.length )
                {
                    usage();
                }
                endPage = Integer.parseInt( args[i] );
            }
            else if( args[i].equals( CONSOLE ) )
            {
                toConsole = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if( pdfFile == null )
                {
                    pdfFile = args[i];
                }
                else
                {
                    outputFile = args[i];
                }
            }
        }

        if( pdfFile == null )
        {
            usage();
        }
        else
        {

            Writer output = null;
            PDDocument document = null;
            try
            {
                long startTime = startProcessing("Loading PDF "+pdfFile);
                if( outputFile == null && pdfFile.length() >4 )
                {
                    outputFile = new File( pdfFile.substring( 0, pdfFile.length() -4 ) + ext ).getAbsolutePath();
                }
                document = PDDocument.load(new File( pdfFile ), password);

                AccessPermission ap = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();
                if( ! ap.canExtractContent() )
                {
                    throw new IOException( "You do not have permission to extract text" );
                }

                stopProcessing("Time for loading: ", startTime);

                if( toConsole )
                {
                    output = new OutputStreamWriter( System.out, encoding );
                }
                else
                {
                    if (toHTML && !STD_ENCODING.equals(encoding))
                    {
                        encoding = STD_ENCODING;
                        System.out.println("The encoding parameter is ignored when writing html output.");
                    }
                    output = new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream( outputFile ), encoding );
                }
                startTime = startProcessing("Starting text extraction");
                if (debug)
                {
                    System.err.println("Writing to " + outputFile);
                }

                PDFTextStripper stripper;
                if(toHTML)
                {
                    // HTML stripper can't work page by page because of startDocument() callback
                    stripper = new PDFText2HTML();
                    stripper.setSortByPosition(sort);
                    stripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(separateBeads);
                    stripper.setStartPage(startPage);
                    stripper.setEndPage(endPage);

                    // Extract text for main document:
                    stripper.writeText(document, output);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (rotationMagic)
                    {
                        stripper = new FilteredTextStripper();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                    }
                    stripper.setSortByPosition(sort);
                    stripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(separateBeads);

                    // Extract text for main document:
                    extractPages(startPage, Math.min(endPage, document.getNumberOfPages()), 
                                 stripper, document, output, rotationMagic, alwaysNext);
                }

                // ... also for any embedded PDFs:
                PDDocumentCatalog catalog = document.getDocumentCatalog();
                PDDocumentNameDictionary names = catalog.getNames();    
                if (names != null)
                {
                    PDEmbeddedFilesNameTreeNode embeddedFiles = names.getEmbeddedFiles();
                    if (embeddedFiles != null)
                    {
                        Map<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> embeddedFileNames = embeddedFiles.getNames();
                        if (embeddedFileNames != null)
                        {
                            for (Map.Entry<String, PDComplexFileSpecification> ent : embeddedFileNames.entrySet()) 
                            {
                                if (debug)
                                {
                                    System.err.println("Processing embedded file " + ent.getKey() + ":");
                                }
                                PDComplexFileSpecification spec = ent.getValue();
                                PDEmbeddedFile file = spec.getEmbeddedFile();
                                if (file != null && "application/pdf".equals(file.getSubtype()))
                                {
                                    if (debug)
                                    {
                                        System.err.println("  is PDF (size=" + file.getSize() + ")");
                                    }
                                    InputStream fis = file.createInputStream();
                                    PDDocument subDoc = null;
                                    try 
                                    {
                                        subDoc = PDDocument.load(fis);
                                        if (toHTML)
                                        {
                                            // will not really work because of HTML header + footer
                                            stripper.writeText( subDoc, output );
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            extractPages(1, subDoc.getNumberOfPages(),
                                                         stripper, subDoc, output, rotationMagic, alwaysNext);
                                        }
                                    } 
                                    finally 
                                    {
                                        fis.close();
                                        IOUtils.closeQuietly(subDoc);                                       
                                    }
                                }
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
                stopProcessing("Time for extraction: ", startTime);
            }
            finally
            {
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
                IOUtils.closeQuietly(document);
            }
        }
    }

    private void extractPages(int startPage, int endPage,
            PDFTextStripper stripper, PDDocument document, Writer output,
            boolean rotationMagic, boolean alwaysNext) throws IOException
    {
        for (int p = startPage; p <= endPage; ++p)
        {
            stripper.setStartPage(p);
            stripper.setEndPage(p);
            try
            {
                if (rotationMagic)
                {
                    PDPage page = document.getPage(p - 1);
                    int rotation = page.getRotation();
                    page.setRotation(0);
                    AngleCollector angleCollector = new AngleCollector();
                    angleCollector.setStartPage(p);
                    angleCollector.setEndPage(p);
                    angleCollector.writeText(document, new NullWriter());
                    // rotation magic
                    for (int angle : angleCollector.getAngles())
                    {
                        // prepend a transformation
                        // (we could skip these parts for angle 0, but it doesn't matter much)
                        PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(document, page,
                                PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.PREPEND, false);
                        cs.transform(Matrix.getRotateInstance(-Math.toRadians(angle), 0, 0));
                        cs.close();

                        stripper.writeText(document, output);

                        // remove prepended transformation
                        ((COSArray) page.getCOSObject().getItem(COSName.CONTENTS)).remove(0);
                    }
                    page.setRotation(rotation);
                }
                else
                {
                    stripper.writeText(document, output);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                if (!alwaysNext)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                LOG.error("Failed to process page " + p, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private long startProcessing(String message) 
    {
        if (debug) 
        {
            System.err.println(message);
        }
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void stopProcessing(String message, long startTime) 
    {
        if (debug)
        {
            long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float elapsedTime = ((float)(stopTime - startTime))/1000;
            System.err.println(message + elapsedTime + " seconds");
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage requirements and exit.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        String message = "Usage: java -jar pdfbox-app-x.y.z.jar ExtractText [options] <inputfile> [output-text-file]\n"
            + "\nOptions:\n"
            + "  -password <password>        : Password to decrypt document\n"
            + "  -encoding <output encoding> : UTF-8 (default) or ISO-8859-1, UTF-16BE,\n"
            + "                                UTF-16LE, etc.\n"
            + "  -console                    : Send text to console instead of file\n"
            + "  -html                       : Output in HTML format instead of raw text\n"
            + "  -sort                       : Sort the text before writing\n"
            + "  -ignoreBeads                : Disables the separation by beads\n"
            + "  -debug                      : Enables debug output about the time consumption\n"
            + "                                of every stage\n"
            + "  -alwaysNext                 : Process next page (if applicable) despite\n"
            + "                                IOException (ignored when -html)\n"
            + "  -rotationMagic              : Analyze each page for rotated/skewed text,\n"
            + "                                rotate to 0° and extract separately\n"
            + "                                (slower, and ignored when -html)\n"
            + "  -startPage <number>         : The first page to start extraction (1 based)\n"
            + "  -endPage <number>           : The last page to extract (1 based, inclusive)\n"
            + "  <inputfile>                 : The PDF document to use\n"
            + "  [output-text-file]          : The file to write the text to";

        System.err.println(message);
        System.exit( 1 );
    }
}

/**
 * Collect all angles while doing text extraction. Angles are in degrees and rounded to the closest
 * integer (to avoid slight differences from floating point arithmethic resulting in similarly
 * angled glyphs being treated separately). This class must be constructed for each page so that the
 * angle set is initialized.
 */
class AngleCollector extends PDFTextStripper
{
    private final Set<Integer> angles = new TreeSet<Integer>();

    AngleCollector() throws IOException
    {
    }

    Set<Integer> getAngles()
    {
        return angles;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text)
    {
        Matrix m = text.getTextMatrix();
        m.concatenate(text.getFont().getFontMatrix());
        int angle = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m.getShearY(), m.getScaleY())));
        angle = (angle + 360) % 360;
        angles.add(angle);
    }
}

/**
 * TextStripper that only processes glyphs that have angle 0.
 */
class FilteredTextStripper extends PDFTextStripper
{
    FilteredTextStripper() throws IOException
    {
    }

    @Override
    protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text)
    {
        Matrix m = text.getTextMatrix();
        m.concatenate(text.getFont().getFontMatrix());
        int angle = (int) Math.round(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(m.getShearY(), m.getScaleY())));
        if (angle == 0)
        {
            super.processTextPosition(text);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Dummy output.
 */
class NullWriter extends Writer
{
    @Override
    public void write(char[] cbuf, int off, int len) throws IOException
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() throws IOException
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ` don't use this on documents you're saving`?

Comment: Will this affect normal PDF that aren't rotated?

Comment: Because the documents are modified, an existing page level rotation is removed. Yes it will work with normal PDFs too (did you even try?). It is just a bit slower than without the option.

Comment: I have yet to try. I was understanding the solution you posted as it seems to have a lot of declaration and new methods. So that's that.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Is there a specific reason why the angle used is calculated from `m.getShearY()` and `m.getScaleY()` instead of `m.getShearX()` and `m.getScaleX()`? At first glance the latter would be the angle of the baseline, and wouldn't it make sense to use the baseline angle? There are some poor man's italics, after all, that would manipulate the former while clearly belonging to the text with the unchanged baseline angle...

Comment: @mkl Probably from some math website... I remember that I thought that there could be a case where one would be different to the other, but I didn't think about italics at that time.

I created a file by using `contents.transform(new Matrix(1, 0, 0.5f, 1, 0, 0));` to get italics and then traced through ExtractText - the angle is 0, so it works.

Comment: *"... the angle is 0, so it works"* - ah right... ok, so my first glance was wrong, it's the other way around, `m.getShearY()` and `m.getScaleY()` determine the angle of the baseline. (Sometimes hard to correctly grasp that... ;) )