# PdfBox removes spaces when text is not oriented correctly

Tags: java, pdfbox

The code below is a simple demonstration of PdfBox found on the internet:

```
public class PDFReader {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = null;
        PDDocument pdDoc = null;
        COSDocument cosDoc = null;
        File file = new File("C:/my.pdf");
        try {
            PDFParser parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
            parser.parse();
            cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
            pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
            pdfStripper.setStartPage(1);
            pdfStripper.setEndPage(5);
            String parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
            System.out.println(parsedText);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly fine unless the text is oriented incorrectly.   For example:  Given a pdf file with the text: "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog."   A pdf with the text upside down will be rendered as `Thequickbrownfoxjumpedoverthelazydog` And if rotated 90 degrees the text looks like this:

```
T
h
e
q
u
i
c
k  
etc.
```

Is there a way to detect orientation prior to stripping the text and then adjusting it to preserve the spacing in the original document?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773479/java-rotated-file-extraction maybe that is some help for you, that answer helped me when I needed to extract some 30 degree rotated text from manually scanned and OCR'ed PDFs

Comment: Theoretically PDFBox attempts to make up for rotation during text extraction. Can you share your test PDFs and tell us which version you use?

Comment: I am finding that it does correct rotation during text extraction but with the side effects as described above. Unfortunately, the documents I'm working with contain Patient Health Information and can't be shared.

Answer (score 1):

ItFreak's comment above pointed me to a stackoverflow question with a comment that solved the problem.   All that was necessary was to set the PdfStripper as follows:

```
stripper.setSortByPosition(true)
```

Once I did this, all the spacing was restored on both the upsidedown and 90 degree rotated images.